# Calculating the frequency of a factor with specific formula

Tags: r

I have data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame( ID = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"), 
                       levels = c( "Y", "R", "O","Y", "R", "O","Y", "R", "O" ),
                       Counts=c(5,1,5,10,2,1,3,5,8))

  ID levels Counts
  A      Y      5
  A      R      1
  A      O      5
  B      Y     10
  B      R      2
  B      O      1
  C      Y      3
  C      R      5
  C      O      8
```

I want to create another column that has a percentage of the second column(levels) like this formula

```
freq=(Y+O/Y+O+R)*100
```

So now the data frame should look like this :

```
ID freq
A  0.1
B  0.2
C  0.3
```

I tried a couple of solutions but it did not work can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `match` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(freq = (Counts[match('Y', levels)] + Counts[match('O', levels)])/sum(Counts))

#   ID     freq
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     0.909
#2 B     0.846
#3 C     0.688
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pivot_wider`

```
df1 %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, values_from = Counts, names_from = levels) %>%
  mutate(freq = (Y+O/Y+O+R)*100,
         freq. = (Y+O)/(Y+O+R)*100) # %>% select(-Y, -R, -O)

  ID        Y     R     O  freq freq.
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         5     1     5 1200   90.9
2 B        10     2     1 1310   84.6
3 C         3     5     8 1867.  68.8
```

I'm not sure what does your formula want.